# Schema.rb doesn't understand SQLite virtual tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, full-text-search

I am using sqlite's FTS4 full-text-search functionality. The FTS table is created via a raw-sql migration using `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_foo USING fts4();` When this is executed SQLite actually creates several tables `fts_foo`, `fts_foo_content`, `fts_foo_docsize`, `fts_foo_segdir`, `fts_foo_segments`, `fts_foo_stat`, as well as an index on `fts_foo_segdir` columns.

However, `schema.rb` does not understand these columns and outputs the following

```ruby
# Could not dump table "fts_foo" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'content'

# Could not dump table "fts_foo_content" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'c0content'

create_table "fts_foo_docsize", :primary_key => "docid", :force => true do |t|
  t.binary "size"
end

create_table "fts_foo_segdir", :primary_key => "level", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "idx"
  t.integer "start_block"
  t.integer "leaves_end_block"
  t.integer "end_block"
  t.binary  "root"
end

add_index "fts_foo_segdir", ["level", "idx"], :name => "sqlite_autoindex_fts_foo_segdir_1", :unique => true

create_table "fts_foo_segments", :primary_key => "blockid", :force => true do |t|
  t.binary "block"
end

create_table "fts_foo_stat", :force => true do |t|
  t.binary "value"
end
```

I don't think any of these tables should be created in schema.rb. It should simply create a single virtual table and let sqlite build the supporting tables. Is there any way I can do this? If not, what kind of work-arounds would facilitate this?